# Perl to extract data between single single quotes considering begin and end values

Tags: text-processing, perl

i have data like below, need to extract only 5 bullet point I added below, since i have multiple entries in same line (this data is in single line) I am able to get partially what I need but not exact data i need
Kindly help

**Data**

```
ABC+222:488665406:2::XYABC:1:1+20230203:195153917+1+20230203:195153917'VAI+I:KK+CH:XXXABC'MGA+N:NNNN+1+1+20230204'VAK+I:KKIIII+TKN:4+test'LRI+N:KK+TKN:1'FSE+N:KNNNNNNN+24+1'FSR+N:KNNNNN+129+1'FSR+N:KNNNNN+130+1'FSR+N:KNNNNN+118+1'FSL+N:K+R11'FSM+N:KNNNNN+R11I42+1++20230204++4'LRI+N:KK+TKN:572'FSE+N:KNNNNNNN+24+1
'LRI+N:KK+TKN:402'FSE+N:KNNNNNNN+12+27+1'FST+N:KNNNNN+2'FSR+N:KNNNNN+28+1+94+20230101'FSM+E:KEEEEE+M11I02+16++20230203++14'LRI+N:KK+TKN:120'FSE+N:KNNNNNNN+70+1++20180101'LRI+N:KK+TKN:333'FSE+N:KNNNNNNN+52+18++20140701'LRI+N:KK+TKN:816'FSR+N:KNNNNN+27+1+94'FST+N:KNNNNN+3'FSL+N:K+M01'FSM+N:KNNNNN+ABCD+1++20230204++4'
FSL+N:K+M10'FSM+N:KNNNNN+XXXX+1++20230204++4'FSL+N:K+M11'FSM+N:KNNNNN+M11I09+16++20230204++4'FSM+N:KNNNNN+M11I01+17++20230204++4'FSM+N:KNNNNN+M11I02+17++20230204++4'FSL+N:K+M08'FSM+N:KNNNNN+M08P02+1++20230204++4'FSN+N:KNNNNNNNNNN+M08P0201+T1:814:aaa:1+4'FSN+N:KNNNNNNNNNN+M08P0203+T1:814:50000000:1+4
'FSL+N:K+E13'FSM+N:KNNNNN+BABX+1++20230204++4'
```

- `VAI+I:KK+CH:XXXABC`  will always be present
- `LRI+N:KK+TKN:402` may be present, maybe not, if yes then print (`TKN:402` is the key here)
- `FSM+E:KEEEEE+M11I02+16++20230203++14` may be present, maybe not, if yes then print (`M11I02` and `14` is the key here)
- `LRI+N:KK+TKN:816` may be available, maybe not, if yes then print (`TKN:816` is the key here)
- `FSM+N:KNNNNN+M11I02+17++20230204++4` may be available, maybe not, if yes then print (`M11I02` and `4` is the key here)

At the end the script give the output as below, if not available then it should find the next one

```
VAI+I:KK+CH:XXXABC|LRI+N:KK+TKN:402|FSM+E:KEEEEE+M11I02+16++20230203++14|LRI+N:KK+TKN:816| FSM+N:KNNNNN+M11I02+17++20230204++4
```

**CODE I tried**

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
       use strict;
       use Data::Dumper;     
       my $filename = $ARGV[0];
       chomp($filename);
       open(FILE,$filename);
       my ($VAI,$LRI,$FSM,$LRI1,$FSM1);
       while(my $data = <FILE>) {
              #print $data;
              ($VAI,$LRI,$FSM,$LRI1,$FSM1) = "";
           if($data =~ /('VAI.*?)(.*?)(\')/) {
               $VAI = "$1$2";
               }
           if($data =~ /('LRI.*TKN:402)(.*?)(\')/) {
               $LRI = "$1$2";
               }
           if($data =~ /('FSM.*?)(.*?)(M11I02)(14\')/) {
               $FSM = "$1$2$3";
               }
           if($data =~ /('LRI.*TKN:816)(.*?)(\')/) {
               $LRI1 = "$1$2$3$4";
               }
           if($data =~ /('FSM.?)(.*?)(M11I02)(4\')/) {
               $FSM1 = "$1$2$3";
               }
           print ("$VAI,$LRI,$FSM,$LRI1,$FSM1\n");
               }
       close(FILE);
```

Comment: you don't need to do that `$filename=$ARGV[0]`...`open(FILE,$filename)` stuff.  Just use `while(my $data = <>) {` and perl while automatically open any filename(s) on the command line (and read from stdin too).   You don't even need the `$data` variable, either.  You can use `while(<>) { ... }` and perl will read from stdin/filenames and assign each input record to a variable called `$_` - which is the default operand for lots of operators and functions.

Comment: Also, when you do need to use `open()`, don't use the two-argument version, it can be unsafe (e.g. if the filename starts with `>` or `|`).  Use the three arg version instead `open($file_handle, '<', $filename)` - where the 2nd arg is the mode (`<` is read).  And don't use bare word file-handles - they still work, but they're discouraged - use a variable instead.   See `perldoc -f open`.

Comment: Hi, I note your Sample Input is on four (4) lines, and at least one of your desired strings appears unquoted ( the string `LRI+N:KK+TKN:816` appears between two quoted strings, if each line is read separately). Do you mean all text should be on one line before starting? And/or each single-quote should be interpreted as two single-quotes, side-by-side? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% clear what your requirements are, especially with repeated instances of the strings you want to match.

Assuming for now you want to match the 5 patterns exactly once, you don't need to get into complex regular expressions if the strings you want to match are fixed literal strings.

Here is a self-contained simple proof-of-concept that does the matching.

Points to note

1. The regular expressions all use the `\Q`, `\E` to escape the `+` characters -- this is a regex metacharacter and needs to be excaped. See [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta) for more details.
2. The code separates the matched patterns with newlines, just to make it easier to read.

```perl
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;     

my $data = q<ABC+222:488665406:2::XYABC:1:1+20230203:195153917+1+20230203:195153917'VAI+I:KK+CH:XXXABC'MGA+N:NNNN+1+1+20230204'VAK+I:KKIIII+TKN:4+test'LRI+N:KK+TKN:1'FSE+N:KNNNNNNN+24+1'FSR+N:KNNNNN+129+1'FSR+N:KNNNNN+130+1'FSR+N:KNNNNN+118+1'FSL+N:K+R11'FSM+N:KNNNNN+R11I42+1++20230204++4'LRI+N:KK+TKN:572'FSE+N:KNNNNNNN+24+1 'LRI+N:KK+TKN:402'FSE+N:KNNNNNNN+12+27+1'FST+N:KNNNNN+2'FSR+N:KNNNNN+28+1+94+20230101'FSM+E:KEEEEE+M11I02+16++20230203++14'LRI+N:KK+TKN:120'FSE+N:KNNNNNNN+70+1++20180101'LRI+N:KK+TKN:333'FSE+N:KNNNNNNN+52+18++20140701'LRI+N:KK+TKN:816'FSR+N:KNNNNN+27+1+94'FST+N:KNNNNN+3'FSL+N:K+M01'FSM+N:KNNNNN+ABCD+1++20230204++4' FSL+N:K+M10'FSM+N:KNNNNN+XXXX+1++20230204++4'FSL+N:K+M11'FSM+N:KNNNNN+M11I09+16++20230204++4'FSM+N:KNNNNN+M11I01+17++20230204++4'FSM+N:KNNNNN+M11I02+17++20230204++4'FSL+N:K+M08'FSM+N:KNNNNN+M08P02+1++20230204++4'FSN+N:KNNNNNNNNNN+M08P0201+T1:814:aaa:1+4'FSN+N:KNNNNNNNNNN+M08P0203+T1:814:50000000:1+4 'FSL+N:K+E13'FSM+N:KNNNNN+BABX+1++20230204++4'> ;

my ($VAI,$LRI,$FSM,$LRI1,$FSM1);


($VAI,$LRI,$FSM,$LRI1,$FSM1) = "";

if($data =~ /'(\QVAI+I:KK+CH:XXXABC\E)'/) {
    $VAI = $1;
}

if($data =~ /'(\QLRI+N:KK+TKN:402\E)'/) {
    $LRI = $1;
}

if($data =~ /'(\QFSM+E:KEEEEE+M11I02+16++20230203++14\E)'/) {
    $FSM = $1 ;
}

if($data =~ /'(\QLRI+N:KK+TKN:816\E)'/) {
    $LRI1 = $1;
}

if($data =~ /'(\QFSM+N:KNNNNN+M11I02+17++20230204++4\E)'/) {
    $FSM1 = $1;
}

print "$_\n" for ($VAI, $LRI, $FSM, $LRI1, $FSM1);
```

outputs

```
VAI+I:KK+CH:XXXABC
LRI+N:KK+TKN:402
FSM+E:KEEEEE+M11I02+16++20230203++14
LRI+N:KK+TKN:816
FSM+N:KNNNNN+M11I02+17++20230204++4
```

If there are extra requirements for handling repeated instances of the patterns you are matching, please update the question with an example that shows what  the output should be in that use-case.